# Trying to make jekyll github page, but gemfile not exist error pops up

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages, gemfile

[image: 1]

Like this  How can I fix it?

I tried changing the baseurl to "/" on _config.yml and added Setup-ruby code to build-test file.
I forked jekyll theme repo and only changed _config.yml so far.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll) are confusing. Just add a Gemfile to the root of your project with the following content:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
```